# Restart a vbs script if it crashes

Tags: vbscript, crash, restart

I'm trying to make a vb script that will restart another vb script if it crashes.
I have searched, and searched but all I get is how to restart a program and since a vb script is a background process it doesn't work when you search in Win32_Process.

Here is my code

```
set Service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sEXEName = "Test_To_Block.vbs"

while true
 bRunning = false

 for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
  if Process.Name = sEXEName then
   bRunning=true
   msgbox("I am active")
  End If
 next


if bRunning=False then
 msgbox("I am not active.")
 Shell.Run sEXEName
end if


WScript.Sleep(100)

wend
```

The problem is that it never see's the file running and just opens hundreds of "Test_To_Stop.vbs"'s which resolves in me having to restart the computer.

In my opinion what should be changed is where the code is looking for.

```
for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")
```

Instead of looking in "Win32_Process" you need to look in wherever background process' run.

I am new to coding so sorry if this is a simple question.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

A Viper

Comment: You can use [`WshShell` object](https://www.google.ru/search?q=WshScriptExec) `.Exec("wscript.exe ""C:\Test\Test_To_Block.vbs"""` method to run the script to be traced, this method returns `WshScriptExec` object, checking it's `.Status` property you may obtain the traced process is terminated, and restart it. You may even combine all the functionality within one script file which would launch itself.

Comment: @omega I like your idea on putting everything in one code, but how is it still gonna track the process if the code has an error, doesn't the code just end?

Comment: @omega Thanks in advance!

Comment: @omega I am new to scripting as I said, could you please give an example of your method. I think it is 'Set Shell = WshShell.Exec("wscript.exe ""C:\Test\Test_To_Block.vbs""")' and then in order to check 'If objWshShell.Status = ????? then' 'restart' I don't know if that is correct, could you please correct me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code restarts itself via `WshShell.Exec()` method and trace state of the running script via `.Status` property of returned object:

```vb
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("task") Then
    Do
        With CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("""" & WScript.FullName & """ """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ ""/task""")
            Do While .Status = 0
                WScript.Sleep 1
            Loop
        End With
    Loop
End If

MsgBox "This script will be restarted immediately after termination"
```

Another way is to use `.Run()` method with third parameter set to `True` to wait until launched process terminated:

```vb
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("task") Then
    Do
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.FullName & """ """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ ""/task""", 1, True
    Loop
End If

MsgBox "This script will be restarted immediately after termination"
```

Or even simplier:

```vb
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("task") Then
    Do
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ ""/task""", 1, True
    Loop
End If

MsgBox "This script will be restarted immediately after termination"
```

Comment: I tried using this an it just hogs my CPU, maybe it doesn't see the program? This is what it is called as when I start any '.vbs' "Microsoft ® Windows Based Script".

Comment: The code works fine for me, may be there are some issues with WSH on your PC? Try to run .vbs file containing the only line with `MsgBox`.

Comment: Yes, the msgbox works fine. But about the WSH, what windows are you using? I have a windows 10.

Comment: What I mean by the comment before is the same thing the answer bellow you says. "Probably because the name of the running process is 'wscript.exe' and not 'Test_To_Block.vbs'. You may be able to use the hack mentioned on this page to change the name of the process:" But his way doesn't work for me, maybe I misunderstood it?

Comment: I'm on Win 7 HB x64 laptop. I will try to test the code on another laptop with Win 10 later.

Comment: Thanks, that could work, I am trying to learn how to use '.exe' so I can try doing it that way!

Comment: @AViper check update, I added the example using `.Run` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144750/discussion-between-omegastripes-and-a-viper).

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the name of the running process is 'wscript.exe' and not 'Test_To_Block.vbs'. You may be able to use the hack mentioned on [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/WJJObekr7HE) page to change the name of the process:

If you're running the scripts locally and running some regular scripts, one
common hack is just to copy and rename wscript.exe to a particular name,
such as "MyScript1.exe".  Then run the script with a shortcut as
"...\MyScript1.exe MyScript1.vbs".  Then the process will show up as
MyScript1.exe.

Then you can use `sEXEName = "MyScript1.exe"`

Note: instead of using  `Shell.run sExeName` use `Shell.run "Test_To_Block.vbs"`

Comment: My codes name is "Microsoft ® Windows Based Script" and if I just check for wscript.exe then it's probably just gonna see itself. I tried your "renaming" system but it didn't work. Thanks in advance!