# Restart vb script

Tags: vbscript, restart

I'm trying to make a Vb script that restarts another vbs script the problem is I'm new to this and I don't know how to do this, someone suggested using `WshShell` I have tried a few websites on how to use it but nothing. Here is what I've got,

```
Dim WshShell, oExec
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("Test_To_Block.vbs")
Do
If NOT WshShell.Status = 1 then
    WScript.Exec("Test_To_Block.vbs")
End If
WScript.Sleep(100)
Loop
```

Thanks,

Regards,

A Viper

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43968275/edit) and update with the code [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43968275) instead of creating new one.

Comment: I try but it says anwsered, which means noone will open it, but the anwser doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Exec` method to run another VB Script, but you are likely to get a console window flash.

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Exec("CMD /C Test_To_Block.vbs")
```

Refer to  [*SS64* site](https://ss64.com/vb/) to learn about VB Script basics.

Comment: I tried testing it but even with the Exec method when I end the other script it is still = 1. For some reason it always sets 'Test_To_Block.vbs' to 1 even when I end 'Test_To_Block.vbs'.

Comment: @AViper What do you mean by set to 1? A property or method of `Run` or something?

Comment: No, the Exec method tracks the program it started, if the program is still running it is equal to 1 else it is equal to 0.

Comment: Then you mean even if your Test_To_Block.vbs finished running, `Exec` returns 1 ??

Comment: Can you please upload your complete VB Script to cloud and provide a link?

Comment: @GTAVLover [the question should be complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the necessary code should be posted within.

Comment: @GTAVLover This is all the code I have so far. What do you mean by complete? Do you wan't me to upload "Test_To_Block.vbs"?

Comment: @A Viper yes if you like.

Answer (score -2):

```
Set x=CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
X.run "file name.vbs"
```